# Hardwood spot refinishing

Tags: hardwood-floor

A dog urine stain has dulled an area on our polyurethane coated hardwood floor. Can we spot repair this area? You can only notice it in certain lights.

Comment: If the urine soaked into the hardwood then consider that spot permanently stained; the only correct repair is to replace that section of hardwood. If it only dulled the superficial polyurethane then you can scuff it up along with surrounding edges and spray on new polyurethane from a can. Don't expect it to look perfect though.

Comment: Scuff it up with sandpaper that is.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a water based poly? I have not seen “oil based” poly affected beyond the surface in that case a fine sand paper can be used to remove the surface layer and recoat. If it is a water based poly you might have to take the surface all the way down to the wood.

Spot refinishing is the hardest thing to blend and although this may make the area clear.  With cases the poly has aged and the new poly may be slightly clearer on the patched area so if it’s hard to tell I might use a fine paper (600+) to buff it out and recoat. This can give a new look to the entire floor if buffed and recoated but wiping all the dust is the critical thing here.

I have had better results with oil based but have been using it for over 40 years, water based is a bit different to me so I go back to oil unless the original was water based.

Comment: Yet another 2 downvotes with no comment. Cowards can’t give a reason because there is none at least I provide a reason.

Comment: Thank you there has been a lot of old questions getting downvotes lately some 2 years old .

Comment: I'll refer you to [this](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1563/34147)

Comment: @freeman Ok I will go through and upvote questions not right to get a downvote for answering and if that’s the reason for the downvote it should be explained.